# GET doesn't work with .htaccess clean url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a profile system, and using `localhost/profiles?user=ryr11` works, and I tried to use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profiles/(.+)$ profiles.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so that I can use `localhost/profiles/ryr11`, but when I do that I no longer get a 404 error, but using `$_GET['user']` no longer works.

Comment: Reorder your rules.  Put the `^profiles/(.+)$` rule before the `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^profiles/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ profiles.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your rules like this:

```
Options  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profiles/(.+)$ profiles.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the url again in order to remove - from it.

Use this

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$postTitle = str_replace("-", " ", $user);
```

This should work again.